# Как перевести string в string массив при последующей возможности редактирования?

Tags: c#

Надо убрать данную ошибку CS0019: `C# operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'`:

```cs
static readonly string[] signs = new[] { "0", "1", ... };

static void Main()
{
    string word = ...;

    for (var i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < signs.Length; j++)
            if (word[i] == signs[i]) // <- ошибка
            {
                word[i] = '\0';

                break;
            }
}
```

Comment: `= ''` (кавычки одинарные, ибо char)

Comment: Приложите код текстом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ про кавычки правильно, но char не может быть пустым.

Comment: Если по быстрому по нужно сравнивать первый символ, а не всю строку.

Comment: Вы бы лучше объяснили - какую задачу выполняет этот код? Явно можно это всё проще написать, нужно только понять, что вы делаете.

Comment: @CrazyElf я всё сразу понял: он пытается удалить невалидные символы из строки и не может их сравнить (ну и нормально удалить). Я уже ответил на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

## Решение

### Про пустой `char`

> char не может быть пустым

А как же `'\0'` (его использую я), или `default/*(char)*/`, или просто `/*(char)*/0` (пустой имеется ввиду значение по умолчанию).

### `RemoveInvalidChars`

```cs
static readonly char[] invalidChars = new[] { /*...*/ };

// `ReadOnlySpan<char>` - ссылка #1
// `StringBuilder` я не рекомендую; используйте `ValueStringBuilder` (ссылки #2,3)
void RemoveInvalidChars(ReadOnlySpan<char> buffer, StringBuilder builder)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        var isValid = true;

        foreach (var invalidChar in invalidChars)
            if (buffer[i] == invalidChar[i])
            {
                isValid = false;

                break;
            }

        if (isValid) builder.Append(buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

### `RemoveInvalidSubstrings`

```cs
static readonly string[] invalidSubtrings = new[] { /*...*/ };

void RemoveInvalidSubstirngs(ReadOnlySpan<char> buffer, StringBuilder builder)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        var isValid = true;

        foreach (var invalidSubstring in invalidSubstrings)
            if (buffer.Length - i >= invalidSubstring.Length &&
                buffer.Slice(i, invalidSubstring.Length)
                    .Equals(invalidSubstring.AsSpan(), StringComparision.Ordinal))
            {
                isValid = false;

                break;
            }

        if (isValid) builder.Append(buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

## Ссылки

- [#1](https://habr.com/ru/post/352716/) – Новинки C# 7.2: Span и Memory
- [#2](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/348130/) – Stackalloc: забытая команда C#
- [#3](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/418911/) – Span: новый тип данных .NET